# control reaches end of non-void function (only on particular IDEs)

Tags: c++, if-statement, gcc-warning

```
int findpow(int n1,int k, int count){ //while calling, k=1, count=0
    if(k<n1)
        return findpow(n1,k*2,count+1);
    if(k==n1)
        return count;
    if(k>n1)
        return --count;
}
```

This is a function that returns the largest power of two less than *n*. When I run it in my ubuntu terminal (g++ 4.8.4), it works fine. But when I am running it on www.hackerrank.com, it gives an error(**control reaches end of non void function**). The problem is, I participate in many contests on this website and I have come across this problem multiple times.

Please tell if you know how I can fix it.

Comment: There are [various faster ways to get the largest power of 2 less than n](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2)

Comment: You should probably learn the difference between a compiler and an IDE.  It would help you ask better questions.

Comment: The compiler is not smart enough to see that function always returns, you have to help it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `else if`  statement like this:

```
int findpow(int n1,int k, int count){ //while calling, k=1, count=0
    if(k<n1)
        return findpow(n1,k*2,count+1);
    else if(k==n1)
        return count;
    else // Eliminate compiler errors (warnings)
        return --count;
}
```

or as said @juanchopanza:

```
int findpow(int n1,int k, int count){ //while calling, k=1, count=0
    if(k<n1)
        return findpow(n1,k*2,count+1);

    if(k==n1)
        return count;

    // Eliminate compiler errors (warnings)
    return --count;
}
```

It will do the same thing as your code, but will not give a doubt to compiler that can be no return points from function.

Comment: Or `return --count;` outside of an `if`.

Answer (score 1):

'control reaches end of non void function' is a warning not  an error, it's safe to ignore in this case but if you want to suppress the warning there are multiple ways:

- put a return after the last condition
- as Mykola suggested restructure the conditions to be explicit
- set the -Wno-return-type flag

Comment: However, if you add a return after the last condition, some compilers will warn about unreachable code. You can't win.

Comment: The last suggestion exposes you to manual hunts for insidious undefined behaviour that the compiler would otherwise have warned about. Restructuring the code is the better option.

Comment: I left it out because i thought it obvious, but for clarity, you can push and pop the warning locally